# Using promises to execute ajax synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-file-upload

This is my code where I handle file uploads:

But as I am not using promises it doesn't run in proper sequence! The ajax part of the code runs at the very end when I upload multiple files (I am using krajee bootstrap and this code does the actual file upload!). Here's the code:

```
$('#uploadNoteImage').on('fileloaded', function (event, file, previewId, index, reader) {
    var url = noTrailingSlash(window.location.href) + '/user/notes';
    console.log("1) Notes upload number: "+index);

    var imgpgno = parseInt(getNotesLength(noteTitle, notesData));
    console.log("2) Got page number of image "+imgpgno);

    var data = {
        "subject": noteTitle,
        "pgno": imgpgno + 1,
        "note": reader.result
    };

    console.log("3) Formed data object:");
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "PUT",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("4) Successfully uploaded data");
            console.log(data);
            toastr.success('', 'Added!');
            var order = getIndexToDelete(noteTitle, notesData);
            console.log("5) Fetched order number: "+order);
            var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
            if (imgpgno == 0) {
                console.log("6)(No notes uploaded yet state) Images before uploading"+images);
                modalImg.src = reader.result;
                notesData[order].data.push({
                    "id": id, "pgno": imgpgno + 1,
                    "note": reader.result
                });
                images = imgpgno + 1;
                console.log("7)(No notes uploaded yet state) Images after uploading: "+images);
                // imgpgno++;

            }
            else if(imgpgno!=0) {
                var newPageNo=imgpgno + 1;
                console.log("6)(1 note uploaded state) Pushing data with pgno: "+newPageNo);
                notesData[order].data.push({
                    "id": id, "pgno": newPageNo,
                    "note": reader.result
                });
                images = imgpgno + 1;
                console.log("7)(1 note uploaded state) Images after uploading: "+images);
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            toastr.error('Try again!', 'Something went wrong in uploading note!');
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

How I can included promises here so that the code runs in proper sequence? I have outlined the problem here in full detail:[Late execution of AJAX code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691628/late-execution-of-ajax-code)

Comment: `Using promises to execute ajax synchronously` - no ... because Promises are asynchronous too - in fact, there is no way to make asynchronous code synchronous - a moments thought about it and you should realise why - and anyway ... $.ajax returns a promise already (a jquery promise, which is 99.9% Promise/A+ spec)

Comment: by the way, the code you presented will console log 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in order - what order do you see?

Comment: the order 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 works for the first file upload! But if i upload 3 files then I get order 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  4 5 6 7. That is the order is totally messed up after first upload :(( If you click the link "Late execution of AJAX code" I have given a link to console screenshot there... Please see it?? And thanks for the prompt reply :)

Comment: well, yes, because each upload is not dependant on the others, so they will complete in different orders - did you want to ensure only one upload is "in flight" at any one time?

Comment: umm i dont understand what in flight means but i want the console sequence as 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 for 3 uploads!! i mean one after other upload with the ajax code running too..!

Comment: In flight means in the process of uploading which takes a finite amount of time. So you only want one upload happening at any one time. Why?

Comment: *Why* do you care about the upload order, is the central question here.

Comment: I want one upload at a time because along with upload i am locally updating some data in the ajax part and the data which will upload after current image upload needs this locally updated data to correctly create the object to upload to database! and right now as the ajax gets executed at the end the object uploaded to database contains in consistent data. In this case the value of  'imgpgno' depends on these local updates so currently 2nd and 3rd upload has same imgpgno which is wrong!!

Comment: I don't really understand. All you do is increment the counter `imgpgno`. What has that to do with the database? Is that supposed to match a database ID or something?

Comment: Yeah but the thing is I make an object which stores image address , its imgno and the order no(reference index) along with other stuff. Now what i want to happen is one file is uploaded , then its object which i create should be pushed locally (which happens in the ajax part ) and only after the push is complete the next file upload should happen!!

Comment: You are too hooked to that *"must happen sequentially"* idea. I get it that in your current setup things must happen sequentially. But that is because your setup is wrong, plain and simple. You *never* want sequential (or worse, synchronous) uploads. If you have multiple files to upload, you want as many parallel uploads as possible. Everything else is a technicality and you can program around that. Identify the technicalities that seem to force sequential order and solve them. That should be your focus. "Sequential uploads" is not the solution.

Comment: Yup I did realies this after I saw the order in which these uploads were happening... But the problem is I am not so good at web development yet and my main skills are in frontend... This back end was programmed by a friend and he is busy right now and I am trying to fix as many bugs as I can as soon as I can so we can publish! Thats why the insist on sequential upload!! :) Thanks for your time :D

Comment: @ParthTamane: Trust me. Front end programmers are much more comfortable with asynchronous code than backend programmers. Front end programmers have had years to get used to `onclick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way requires one little "setup" -

```
var uploadInProgress = $.when();
```

this "primes" the `uploadInProgress` variable in such a way that the first upload will begin as soon as we want it to

the whole code is not very different to the code you already have:

```
var uploadInProgress = $.when();
$('#uploadNoteImage').on('fileloaded', function (event, file, previewId, index, reader) {
    // here, we chain the "pending" upload to this one
    uploadInProgress = uploadInProgress.then(function() {
        var url = noTrailingSlash(window.location.href) + '/user/notes';
        console.log("1) Notes upload number: "+index);

        var imgpgno = parseInt(getNotesLength(noteTitle, notesData));
        console.log("2) Got page number of image "+imgpgno);

        var data = {
            "subject": noteTitle,
            "pgno": imgpgno + 1,
            "note": reader.result
        };

        console.log("3) Formed data object:");
        console.log(data);
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "PUT",
            data: data
        // since we are using Promise pattern, use .then for success, and .catch for error conditions
        }).then(function (data) {
            console.log("4) Successfully uploaded data");
            console.log(data);
            toastr.success('', 'Added!');
            var order = getIndexToDelete(noteTitle, notesData);
            console.log("5) Fetched order number: "+order);
            var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
            if (imgpgno == 0) {
                console.log("6)(No notes uploaded yet state) Images before uploading"+images);
                modalImg.src = reader.result;
                notesData[order].data.push({
                    "id": id, "pgno": imgpgno + 1,
                    "note": reader.result
                });
                images = imgpgno + 1;
                console.log("7)(No notes uploaded yet state) Images after uploading: "+images);
                // imgpgno++;

            }
            else { // if(imgpgno!=0) { // the check is redundant since when the above if condition is false, this has to be true
                var newPageNo=imgpgno + 1;
                console.log("6)(1 note uploaded state) Pushing data with pgno: "+newPageNo);
                notesData[order].data.push({
                    "id": id, "pgno": newPageNo,
                    "note": reader.result
                });
                images = imgpgno + 1;
                console.log("7)(1 note uploaded state) Images after uploading: "+images);
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {
            // this catch ensures that the next upload will be able to run regardless of this upload's failure
            toastr.error('Try again!', 'Something went wrong in uploading note!');
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
});
```

Instead of the `success:`/`error:` callbacks, use the fact that `$.ajax` returns a `Promise`, and use `.then`/`.catch` - this makes it easy to chain the upload requests one after the other

Note: make sure the .catch actually handles the error (i.e. doesn't throw one) or the promise chain will break - the code you had in `error:` is fine as is

Comment: Thanks so much!!! This is working perfectly!! I'll test it further but I don't this there are any issues here... Just I wanted to know one thing, if I remove catch part then all the uploads after one failed upload will also halt, right??

Comment: correct, because the code works on the "resolved" chain - "handling" an error in catch by **not** throwing or returning a "rejected promise" means the chain is unbroken

Comment: Okay!! By the way I don't know why but sometimes the same image is being uploaded to the database twice or thrice! I'm going through the logs to see what is happening but so far all the mata data for each image seems correct! So is there a chance that this code picks up same image multiple times?? Because its not completely synchronous yet? I am trying to recreate the issue so i can show the log!

Comment: Okay there is still a problem! The steps run in proper sequence but more than one image is being uploaded again and again :(( Idk why! Can you please help?

Comment: okay heres what is happeneing so far: 1) First 4 image upload happened correctly. 2) After that the next in the next 4 image upload, the data did go correctly to the data base but locally first image was skipped and the last uploaded image was displayed twice 3) In the next 3 uploaded , the firt image was uploaded properly, second image was skipped and last image was stored 2 times! Any Idea why this could be happening? It's baffling me!! @JaromandaX